# What is the equivalent of the Java BigDecimal class in C#?

Tags: c#, java, bigdecimal, equivalent

`BigDecimal` is a class in the `java.math` package that has a lot of benefits for handling big numbers of a certain scale. Is there an equivalent class or data type in c# with this feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a BigFloat class in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359372/is-there-a-bigfloat-class-in-c)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

C# only has `BigInteger` built it (in .NET framework 4).

Is `decimal` enough precision for your task? It's a 128-bit number that can hold values in the range ±1.0 × 10<sup>−28</sup> to ±7.9 × 10<sup>28</sup>.

Comment: The BigRational class is also on its way. Currently in beta.

Comment: @RaheelKhan do you mean this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.rational(v=vs.93).aspx

Answer (score 46):

Just recently I also needed an arbitrary precision decimal in C# and came across the idea posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524254/804614

I then completed the draft to support all basic arithmetic and comparison operators, as well as conversions to and from all typical numerical types and a few exponential methods, which I needed at that time.

It certainly is not comprehensive, but very functional and almost ready-to-use. As this is the result of one night coding, I can not assure that this thing is bug free or entirely exact, but it worked great for me. Anyway, I want to publish it here because I did not find any other way to use arbitrary precision decimals in C# without the need to include massive librarys (mostly not even .net, but wrappers to c++), which come with all kinds of unnecessary stuff.

The basic idea is to build a custom floating-point type with an arbitrary large mantissa using the BigInteger type of .NET 4.0 and a base 10 exponent (Int32).

If you find bugs/inaccuracies, have suggestions or anything constructive, please feel free to directly edit my post or leave a comment so I may improve the answer.

I'm not entirely sure if this is the best spot to place this thing, but this is one of the top questions on SO about this topic and I really want to share my solution. ;)

EDIT: I moved the implementation to GitHubGist: https://gist.github.com/JcBernack/0b4eef59ca97ee931a2f45542b9ff06d

Comment: Excellent work! This comes in handy for my PI calculation endeavor.

Comment: This is nice.  One suggestion I might make is not to negate the mantissa in your unary `-` operator, instead to return a new `BigDecimal` with the negated mantissa, for immutablilty.  Otherwise you might find that `BigDecimal x = 1.01, y = -x` has the undesired effect of `x == y == -1.01`.

Comment: @jimbobmcgee First I thought you were right and was already editing the answer, but then I realized again that the `BigDecimal` is a struct. That means the argument into the unary operator is already a copy of the original which makes it impossible to accidentally modify it.

Comment: @Gigo - noted and accepted.  A quick `BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1, 0); BigDecimal minusOne = -one; (new { one, minusOne }).Dump("negation?");` in LINQPad confirms it.  Good to learn something new, today!

Comment: I think you need to do another `Normalize` whenever you `Truncate`, otherwise `1.000000005` after `Truncate(8)` is `1.0000000` and doesn't correctly equal `1`.

Comment: @NigelTouch You are right, thanks for pointing that out. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I am using this in our solution and I noticed that division was taking almost 500ms due primarily to the NumberOfDigits function. Converting it to a string is quite time consuming. I replaced the body of that function with this:

`return (int)Math.Ceiling(BigInteger.Log10(value*value.Sign));`

Comment: Thanks, I added your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Well, apart from using third-party libraries with support of the BigDecimal (if they exist), there are no easy workarounds. The most easy way, as far as i am concerned is to take a decimal implementation( from mono for example) and to rewrite it using the BigInteger type. Internally, in mono's implementation, decimal type is composed from three integers. So i don't think that would be hard to implement. I am not sure about efficiency though. You should first however consider using standard decimal type as **codeka** mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

There's a C# library called BigNum that does what you're looking for, and in some cases has additional functionality.

For example, it has a square root function, which BigDecimal doesn't have:

```
PrecisionSpec precision = new PrecisionSpec(1024, PrecisionSpec.BaseType.BIN);
BigFloat bf = new BigFloat(13, precision);
bf.Sqrt();
Console.WriteLine(bf.ToString());
```

Wikipedia has a list of other such libraries at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries

Sources:

- The BigNum library was originally hosted at http://www.fractal-landscapes.co.uk/bigint.html, but that site has been down since 2012. (And then came back up at some point).
- You can find an archive of the site at http://web.archive.org/web/20110721173046/http://www.fractal-landscapes.co.uk/bigint.html.
- There's a copy of the source code at http://www.mediafire.com/file/6axoicc6iszp4sg/BigNum.zip/file

Comment: 404: Library no longer available?

Comment: The link is dead, and archive.org doesn't keep the source code zip files.

Comment: Please, can someone reupload the original for this?

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: @Rasheed I added a link to a zip file containing the source.

Comment: The first link isn't dead anymore. :)  slightly different layout than archived version, but appears to be the same era regardless.

Answer (score 3):

## Deveel Math

## GitHub:

https://github.com/deveel/deveel-math

## Author GitHub:

[Antonello Provenzano](https://github.com/tsutomi)

## Support:

- BigComplex
- BigDecimal
- BigMath
- Rational
- ...

## How to Install It

From the NuGet Package Management console, select the project where the library will be installed and type the following command

```
PM> Install-Package dmath
```

Comment: I wouldn't trust this library. I had some cases where an addition failed with an error "power of 10 too big" as well as another case using BigDecimal where 0.5 > 1e-20 returns false

Comment: Excellent library

Answer (score 2):

This may not have been an option when the question was originally posted, but one really easy way to use a `BigDecimal` in your C# code is to install the [IKVM.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IKVM/) package via NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package IKVM
```

Then do exactly as you would in Java:

```
using System;
using java.math;

namespace BigDecimalDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(Factorial(n));
        }

        static BigDecimal Factorial(int n)
        {
            return n == 1
                ? BigDecimal.ONE
                : Factorial(n - 1).multiply(new BigDecimal(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on how far you go with IKVM there can be the occasional interop issue to stumble through but in my experience it usually works great for simple stuff like this.

Comment: IKVM is great tool for bringing in java code into a C# project, but adding the entire java class libraries to your project just to bring in one relatively simple class seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Math.Gmp.Native](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Math.Gmp.Native.NET/) NuGet package that I wrote. Its source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MachineCognitis/Math.Gmp.Native/), and documentation is available [here](https://machinecognitis.github.io/Math.Gmp.Native/html/846f5c8a-6cba-433e-9f18-cde2ff5695cd.htm). It exposes to .NET all of the functionality of the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library which is known as a highly-optimized arbitrary-precision arithmetic library.

Arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers are represented by the [mpf_t](https://machinecognitis.github.io/Math.Gmp.Native/html/37c88d6c-8d02-2330-ad77-f20fb73d1677.htm) type. Operations on these floating-point numbers all begin with the `mpf_` prefix. For examples, [mpf_add](https://machinecognitis.github.io/Math.Gmp.Native/html/c19999f1-01ee-a3fe-dc4d-2a459e73492d.htm) or [mpf_cmp](https://machinecognitis.github.io/Math.Gmp.Native/html/be9e6a25-83fb-49c2-949a-b8642a8234f5.htm). Source code examples are given for each operation.