# C# Double Rounding

Tags: c#, java, double

I'm currently working on a program and im converting my java code into c# . but i'm having some trouble.

```
public double round(double value){
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(value);
        b = b.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
        return (b.doubleValue());
    }
```

i wrote this converting code but i cant convert it to c#.BigDecimal type causes some problem and im totally new to .Net.Definitely need some help.

Edit : Ok buds i got it , sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Looks like .NET doesn't have an equivalent of Java's BigDecimal -- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-for-java-class-bigdecimal-in-c). It has decimal, but that has only finite precision. Is that sufficient for what you want to do?

Comment: actually i don't need that type at all.all i need is to realize double rounding in the way i did with bigdecimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you just do this to round to 2 fractional digits?

```
        double foo = 3.143;
        double fooRounded = Math.Round(foo, 2);
```

Comment: That will actually use `MidpointRounding.ToEven` by default, which will produce slightly different results than the `ROUND_UP` in the java original.

Comment: @MusiGenesis - Totally Agreed, I was just showing simple rounding with Math.Round, to exactly replicate the behavior as shown in OP's method above your updated answer should be the accepted one - hopefully he's still reading this.

Comment: You'd think the SO experience would teach someone like me the utter lack of value in nitpicking somebody else's code, but no ...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a C# method that you can use instead:

```
public double round(double value){
    return Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);   
}
```

.Net's `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` is the equivalent of java's `ROUND_UP`.