# Rounding mismatch between ASP .net C# Decimal to Java Double

Tags: java, c#, .net, rounding, precision

I am translating .NET code to Java and ran into precision not matching issue.

.NET code:

```
private decimal roundToPrecision(decimal number, decimal roundPrecision)
{
    if (roundPrecision == 0)
        return number;
    decimal numberDecimalMultiplier = Math.Round(number / roundPrecision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    return numberDecimalMultiplier * roundPrecision;
}
```

Calling `roundToPrecision(8.7250, 0.05);` function in the code above gives me `8.75` which is expected.

> The conversion/translation of the function to Java is as follows. I din't find exact
>   `Math.Round` option.

Java code:

```
public double roundToPrecision(double number, double roundPrecision) {
    if (roundPrecision == 0)
        return number;
    int len = Double.toString(roundPrecision).split("\\.")[1].length();
    double divisor = 0d;
    switch (len) {
        case 1:
            divisor = 10d;
            break;
        case 2:
            divisor = 100d;
            break;
        case 3:
            divisor = 1000d;
            break;
        case 4:
            divisor = 10000d;
            break;
    }
    double numberDecimalMultiplier = Math.round(number / roundPrecision);
    double res = numberDecimalMultiplier * roundPrecision;
    return Math.round(res * divisor) / divisor;
}
```

Calling `roundToPrecision(8.7250, 0.05);` in the Java code gives me `8.7`and this is not correct.

I even tried modifying code with `BigDecimal` as follows in Java using the reference here [C# Double Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811488/c-sharp-double-rounding) but have no luck.

```
public double roundToPrecision(double number, double roundPrecision) {
    if (roundPrecision == 0)
        return number;
    int len = Double.toString(roundPrecision).split("\\.")[1].length();
    double divisor = 0d;
    switch (len) {
        case 1:
            divisor = 10d;
            break;
        case 2:
            divisor = 100d;
            break;
        case 3:
            divisor = 1000d;
            break;
        case 4:
            divisor = 10000d;
            break;
    }
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(number / roundPrecision);
    b = b.setScale(len,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    double numberDecimalMultiplier = Math.round(b.doubleValue());
    double res = numberDecimalMultiplier * roundPrecision;
    return Math.round(res * divisor) / divisor;
}
```

Please guide me for what I need to do to fix this.

Here are couple of scenarios to try out.

- number = `10.05`; precision = `.1`; expected = `10.1`;
- number = `10.12`; precision = `.01`; expected = `10.12`;
- number = `8.7250`; precision = `0.05`; expected = `8.75`;
- number = `10.999`; precision = `2`; expected = `10`;
- number = `6.174999999999999`; precision = `0.05`; expected = `6.20`;

Note: I have over 60 thousand numbers and precision can vary from 1 decimal to 4 decimal places. The output of .NET should match exactly to Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem comes from how doubles vs decimals are stored and represented in memory.  See these links for more specifics: [Doubles](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) [Decimals](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx)

Let's take a look at how they each work in your code.  Using doubles, with arguments of 8.725 and 0.05.  `number / roundPrecision` gives `174.499...`, since doubles aren't able to exactly represent 174.5.  With decimals `number / roundPrecision` gives `174.5`, decimals are able to represent this exactly.  So then when `174.499...` gets rounded, it gets rounded down to `174` instead of `175`.

Using `BigDecimal` is a step in the right direction.  There is an issue with how it's being used in your code however.  The problem comes when you're creating the BigDecimal value.

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(number / roundPrecision);
```

The `BigDecimal` is being created from a double, so the imprecision is already there.  If you're able to create the `BigDecimal` arguments from a string that would be much better.

```
public static BigDecimal roundToPrecision(BigDecimal number, BigDecimal roundPrecision) {
    if (roundPrecision.signum() == 0)
        return number;
    BigDecimal numberDecimalMultiplier = number.divide(roundPrecision, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return numberDecimalMultiplier.multiply(roundPrecision);
}


BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("-8.7250");
BigDecimal p = new BigDecimal("0.05");
BigDecimal r = roundToPrecision(n, p);
```

If the function must take in and return doubles:

```
public static double roundToPrecision(double number, double roundPrecision)
{
    BigDecimal numberBig = new BigDecimal(number).
            setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal roundPrecisionBig = BigDecimal.valueOf(roundPrecision);
    if (roundPrecisionBig.signum() == 0)
        return number;
    BigDecimal numberDecimalMultiplier = numberBig.divide(roundPrecisionBig, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return numberDecimalMultiplier.multiply(roundPrecisionBig).doubleValue();
}
```

Keep in mind that doubles cannot exactly represent the same values which decimals can.  So the function returning a double cannot have the exact output as the original C# function which returns decimals.

Comment: Thank for the answer. However, I have already tried this. Try senarios 1 and  2 (I have updated the question). They don't give expected result in your implementation.

Comment: Your solution throws `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result` on `BigDecimal numberDecimalMultiplier = number.divide(roundPrecision).setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING);` when number is 10.0 and precision is 0.1

Comment: What are your arguments when it throws the exception?

Comment: when number is 10.0 and precision is 0.1

Comment: This case fails `number = 10.025d;
 precision = .05d;
 expected = 10.05d;`

Comment: The case works for me.  How are you creating the function arguments?  It looks like they're coming from doubles?

Comment: I cannot modify the argument but rather created double right after passing value to function. `roundToPrecision (10.05, .1)` this results to `10.100000000000001` while expectation is  `10.1`

Comment: 10.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double.  You could use a small epsilon value to compare for equality, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160375/comparing-double-values-for-equality-in-java  Are your round precisions always a multiple of 0.0005?  What are you doing with the values after you round?

Comment: precisions are determined by the logic in the application and cannot be profiled as multiple of anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133384/discussion-between-gunnerone-and-dinesh-devkota).

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that the Math.round has two definitions. One returns a long, while the other returns an int! When you provide a double it runs the one for a long. To fix this simply cast your input to a float, to make it run the one to return the int.

```
double numberDecimalMultiplier = Math.round((float)(number / roundPrecision));
```