# How can I get more than 100 decimal digits in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, bigdecimal

Is it possible to get more than 100 decimal digits in C#?

If yes what is the necessary portion of code?

In Java there something call `BigDecimal` but it still can't reach more than 55 digits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of the Java BigDecimal class in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-java-bigdecimal-class-in-c) (essentially: C# doesn't have one, do you need to use C#?)

Comment: Why the downvote? Questions for high precision arithmetic seems a very normal one, no?

Comment: `System.Decimal` won't work since it only supports about 28 digits. `BigInteger` only supports integers.

Comment: I think you need to use some third party library, such as BigRational http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782

Comment: @Abel: The problem with 'normal questions' is that are asked too often and searched too little. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+biginteger . That's how they become 'normal'

Comment: @CodeInChaos: OR use the Fraction class from IronScheme.

Comment: @leppie: make that an answer and get points for creativity

Comment: @sehe: Nah, making it an answer, means I will have to support it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Using J# libraries:

[Download the J#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vjsharp/bb188598) Redistributable to obtain the J# class libraries. [This article hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx) about how to use it to get ZIP-ability in your .NET projects, and explains a bit about BigDecimal, but as Ramhound explained, the article is relatively old.

After download, add the `vsjlib` to your project. It didn't work for me on .NET 4.0, but it did work on 2.0 project. It contains a BigDecimal class, among others. Not sure, however, if that gives you up to 100 decimals, but you might give it a try.

#### Using MPIR -- Multi Precision Integers and Rationals

You can download a wrapper for the [MPIR](http://mpir.org) library for [.NET here (download version 0.2)](http://www.alglib.net/x/xmpir/). Then, do the following:

- Add the the files `\wrapper.*.dll` to your project, make sure that on each built they are copied to your Debug or Release directory.
- Add `\wrapper\xmpir.cs` to your project
- Add the following code to your project:

  ```
  // set the precision to 512 bits (adjust this to your needs)
  mpir.mpf_set_default_prec(512);
  ulong default_prc = mpir.mpf_get_default_prec();

  // init vars (important!)
  mpir.mpf_t val = mpir.mpf_init_set_d(.5);
  mpir.mpf_t result = mpir.mpf_init_set_ui(0);

  // calculate 0.5^200
  mpir.mpf_pow_ui(result, val, 200);
  double dresult = mpir.mpf_get_d(result);

  // convert result to a string, in the form 1.2345 (dot not in output) and exp holding exponent
  long exp;
  string sresult = mpir.mpf_get_string(out exp, 10, 0, result);

  // free vars (important!)
  mpir.mpf_clear(val);
  mpir.mpf_clear(result);
  ```

Note that the variable `sresult` will only hold the significant digits. You'll have to add the logic for printing the exponent as well, or a bunch of zeroes.

Result is `6.2230152778611417071440640537801242405902521687211671331011166147896988340353834411839448231257136169569665895551224821247160434722900390625E-60`

A [documentation PDF file](http://www.mpir.org/mpir-2.2.0.pdf) on the full MPIR library shows how to use it in more detail.

Comment: thanks for your help but as you know this library use the java implementation of Bigdecimal

Comment: The article is not current.  There is a class to manipulate a Zip file, this has been the clast for at least 5 years, 2 years after the article was written.

Comment: @Ramhound, I updated the text with correct download locations for J#.

Comment: @HusseinX, I added code for the MPIR library wrapper, which is a bit cumbersome to use, but that's because they're from the C++ world. But the documentation is good.

Answer (score -1):

If you use .net Framework 4.0, you can refernce System.Numerics assembly.
or you can download [BigInteger](http://biginteger.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) from codeplex

Usage of BigIngeger : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

for example:

```
string positiveString = "91389681247993671255432112000000";
string negativeString = "-90315837410896312071002088037140000";
BigInteger posBigInt = 0;
BigInteger negBigInt = 0;

try {
   posBigInt = BigInteger.Parse(positiveString);
   Console.WriteLine(posBigInt);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the string '{0}' to a BigInteger value.", 
                     positiveString);
}

if (BigInteger.TryParse(negativeString, out negBigInt))
  Console.WriteLine(negBigInt);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the string '{0}' to a BigInteger value.", 
                      negativeString);

// The example displays the following output:
//   9.1389681247993671255432112E+31
//   -9.0315837410896312071002088037E+34
```

EDITED:
here have a bigNum project http://sine.codeplex.com/

```
using W3b.Sine;

public class ExpressionSample {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {

        Dictionary<String,BigNum> symbols = new Dictionary<String,BigNum>() {
            {"x", 100} // the implicit conversion defined
        };

        Expression expression = new Expression("1 + 2 / 3 * x");
        BigNum result = expression.Evaluate( symbols );
        Console.WriteLine( expression.ExpressionString + " == " + result.ToString() );

        BigNum x = 100;
        BigNum xPow100 = x.Pow( 100 );
        Console.WriteLine("100^100 == " + xPow100.ToString() );

    }
}
```

Comment: How does using a `BigInteger` class help display **decimal** values?

Comment: No, it only calculate ingeger

Comment: You edited the question a few times, but I'm still at a loss how it helps the OP with 100+ digits precision in _floating point arithmetic_ (decimals, that is). You only mention big integers.

Comment: Sine can display decimal value with 100 digits precision. see details in http://sine.codeplex.com/