# VB.net 300 digits in a fraction - numeric data type

Tags: vb.net, types, numeric, digits

I'm looking for a numeric data type that can preserve up to 300 digits.
[I read that article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae55hdtk.aspx)
and I tried double-single but they didn't work, I don't know why but it finishes at digit n25.
Thanks

Ex: I find 0,65857864376269049511983112757903 when I calculate on calculator of my computer but when I calculate it myself using double I get 0,65857864376269.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7887952/864696)

Answer (score 0):

300 significant digits is a lot. System.Double represents up to about 15 digits, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There's no arbitrary-precision float class in the .NET framework that I know of. If you know how many decimal places your numbers will have, and aren't performing a lot of math operations on them, you could look at using [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will store an arbitrary-length integer, and you could then apply a scaling factor whenever you output the number.

If 300 was a typo, and you only need 30 significant digits, that's within the range of quad-precision. That's not built into the framework, but  I see a [quad precision library](https://quadruple.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex, and there are probably others.

Otherwise, you'll need to find or implement your own arbitrary-precision library to handle these values.