# How to store greater value than that of decimal(7.9*10 power 28) data types can hold in c#

Tags: c#

Decimal, float ,long and double etc are the data types present in c#. I found that Decimal data types can hold maximum value of  7.9*10 power 28.

Now, i would like to know, if i need to store greater value than that decimal data types can hold, then how can i do that ?
Similarly , is there any other data types present in C#?

Comment: The answers here may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-java-bigdecimal-class-in-c

Comment: The post @rsbarro mentions answers your question. This answer in particular talks about a [third party library you can use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6165882/368070)

Comment: Are you a space scientist ?
Please give a practical situation when this can occur, and we will give u the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `double` data type can hold values up to some [~1.0 power 300](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (can't remember exact value). If that's not enough for you, then provide us with your real-life example.