# Is C#'s Decimal Type Accounting Safe?

Tags: c#, types, decimal

I [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) that the `Decimal` type has a range of (-7.9 x 10^28 to 7.9 x 10^28) / (10^0 to 10^28) and that it is "appropriate for financial and monetary calculations."

I can't seem to find a source that says that Decimal can represent *to the penny* all values from ($79,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.00) to $79,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.00.

`Decimal` is a 128-bit type, and 128-bits could represent every penny from -10^38 to 10^38. But I don't know how Decimal is implemented, so as with `float`s there could be penny precision loss the further the number goes from 0.

Comment: The rounding errors caused by Decimals are directly transferred to Bill Gate's private banking account.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to keep accuracy _to the penny_ then your "maximim" value is really `Decimal.MaxValue / 100`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Decimal C# - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)

> The Decimal value type represents decimal numbers ranging from
>   positive 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 to negative
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335. The Decimal value type is
>   appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of
>   significant integral and fractional digits and **no round-off errors**.
>   **The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding.**

For more info you may see [Decimal floating point in .NET by Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/decimal.aspx)

Comment: Nice answer. Just adding this for more info: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/decimal.aspx

Comment: If Decimal is not enough accurate (I very much doubt it...) then you can also have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-java-bigdecimal-class-in-c

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to find a source that says that Decimal can represent to the penny all values from ($79,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.00) to $79,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.00.

That's because *it can't*. `decimal` allows *up to* 29 significant digits of precision.  That means if you want to maintain accuracy *to the penny*, then your maximum safe value is really `(Decimal.MaxValue -1)/100` (or `$792,281,625,142,643,375,935,439,503.30`:

```
(Decimal.MaxValue - (Decimal.MaxValue - 0.01m))                  == 0
(Decimal.MaxValue/100- (Decimal.MaxValue/100 - 0.01m))           == 0  // why?
(((Decimal.MaxValue-1)/100)- ((Decimal.MaxValue-1)/100 - 0.01m)) == 0.01
```

Note:  I'm not certain why `Decimal.MaxValue/100` doesn't work, but if `Decimal.MaxValue - 1` is a safe limit then you should be fine.