# Double ToString format with no precision lost and group separators

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the string output of a Double value with group separators and no loss in precision in any culture. Is there anyway to do this without writing my own method to do it?

I know you can use ToString("N0"), but this results in a loss of precision.
I know you can use ToString("R") to keep the precision, but this doesn't include group separators.

E.g.
For Double.MaxValue in Invariant Culture I would like

```
"179,769,313,486,231,570,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000"
```

Edit: When I say loss in precision I mean the full number of significant figures rather than not loosing precision in the 'decmial' part of the value. I want to be able to do 'round trips' with group separators, so ToString -> Parse -> ToString.

Edit 2: For a better comparison of the problem I'm trying to solve here is the output when using ToString("N0"). Here you can see the rounding at the end of the significant figures:

```
"179,769,313,486,232,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000"
```

Comment: There is nothing like *precise* double.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-java-bigdecimal-class-in-c

Comment: [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

Comment: How much precision do you actually need?

Comment: I've edited to explain my use of the word precision above. This is not about decimal precision, but about loss of significant figures in the string.

Comment: The question is what do you need this for? It seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: In my case it is to generate values to test a Double parser in multiple different cultures, but I could definitely see someone wanting this for other reasons. For example I can see someone wanting to output the Single/float "12345678" with group separators without losing the significant figures, but that comes out as 12,345,680 with ToString("N0"). This is the same issue as described above.

Comment: @MarkOwen320 Try `.ToString("r")`

Comment: @Magnus "r" or "R" (I believe they are the same) doesn't give the group separators

Comment: I think it is the best you're gonna get. You can add the group separation yourself afterwards.

Comment: That's what I thought when I posted, but wanted to check if anyone had any alternatives. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like any of the built in ToString formats do what I required.

For my purposes I was able to write a method to deal with the scenarios I had, but since it doesn't work for all possible values I'm not posting it here.

Thanks to all the posters for their assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the format `#,0.#` you will get:

- Thousand separators
- As many decimals as required

That should fulfill your requirement, if I'm reading the question correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work as you loose the significant figures. In the example below you will notice rounding at the '232,000' part, rather than the '231,570' in my original question:
Double.MaxValue.ToString("#,0.#") = "179,769,313,486,232,000,000..."