# Double calculation value in C#

Tags: c#

I have calculation statement in C# as below statement:

```
(-0.0116 * (5.08 - 0.52 * Math.Pow(5.08, 1.3)) * Math.Pow(0.5, 1.1) * (-0.14 * Math.Pow((19000 * 0.5), 0.8)))
```

When I debug and add this statement to watch, it was shows as below screenshot:

[image]

but when assign to double variable, the result was changed:

[image]

How do I get `0.89713135944117184` without changing any of the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum precision of a double in C# is 15 or 16 digits. See [the reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx).

You should use `BigInteger`, assuming you are using .Net 4+. `BigInteger` "Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer." [See the `BigInteger` documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813535/77074) for an example implementation that uses the `BigInteger` class to do decimal based calculations.

Comment: @GrantWinney - Good point. Added a line to provide more guidance for how `BigInteger` can address the OP's need.