# How can I get 28 digit precision on mathematical operations?

Tags: c#, .net, math, decimal

I am in a project of making a scientific calculator in c# (windows forms). I need to perform operations like log,sqrt,trignometric fns etc with decimal type. Is there any way to perform this?
System.Math operate only on double values.
thank you

Comment: there is a decimal datatype available in C#. check [Decimal Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)

Comment: and if `Decimal` isn't enough, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13813535/103167

Comment: I want to perform operations on decimal type.

Comment: is this only a toy-calculator? Don't get me wrong but usually it's no big deal to just convert to `double` and then back to `decimal` if you just want to to write your own *calc.exe*

Comment: it doesn't work for a number with more than 16 digits.

Comment: Who said? **Decimal has roughly 28 digit precision.** if you need more you need something else, if not...

Comment: obviously Decimal has roughly 28 digit precision. but double doesn't. that I said. and I need functions accept decimal type as arguments.

Comment: Build you own. There most of your functions can be found in the math library of the multiprecision calculator bc, http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/bc/1.06/bc/libmath.b Obviously, `scale` is fixed for the Decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using BigInteger:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Split the project so that your calculation logic works with big integer and your GUI shows a user friendly representation of it. For example:

In the logic:

```
BigInteger pi = new BigInteger(31415926535);
```

In the GUI:

```
string pi = (pi/10).ToString(format);
```

Even if you don't work with WPF or MVVM pattern, it is good to have such differences between logic and presentation.