# Adding a class to a library in c#

Tags: c#, class, dll

So I've downloaded a source code from projectcode.com and it's name is  BigInteger.cs and it contains codes needed for working with integers beyond UInt64. How can I use it in my projects?And please be noob-friendly in your answers, I've started learning 3 days ago ...

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is it a class or class library ?

Comment: @HarveySpecter how can I know?

Comment: If its a single file with .cs extension, its a class file and if its a collection of files, its a class library.

Comment: Then it has to be class file.And please since I'm new here,could you explain to me what part of my question was that absurd to get 3 downvotes in a matter of 9 minutes?Isn't this supposed to be a friendly heartwarming community?

Comment: It definitely is. And the reason behind your downvotes is the less amount of detailing in your question. You need to provide more details in terms of explanation or code or links or images or anything. Put up more information so we can directly answer.

Comment: If you want to know how to ask a good question, you can start by reading this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd want to use [`BigInteter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class from .Net Framework. If you need decimal precision as well, there is no standard `BigDecimal` available, but a few workarounds can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2863388/706456).

If you still want to use that project, you have several options:

- Download an assembly file and reference it in your project
- Download source code, build it, reference output assembly in your project
- Download only the needed file, provided it is self-contained, add it to your project and use it

In any case make sure to follow the license terms.

Comment: As much I appreciate your answer,there are hardly any words here I can understand.Could you provide more links for further explanation please?

Comment: @ArianTashakkor If you have trouble with that vocabulary, I strongly recommend to dive into the C# language first, before trying to reference existing code/assemblies. Try to get to know the language first and how projects/solutions are working together etc.