# How to print all the decimal points without rounding up?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate wind_chill by getting temp and wind_speed from user.
All variables are declared as `double`.

```
wind_chill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temp + (0.4275 * temp - 35.75) * System.Math.Pow(wind_speed, 0.16);
```

I am getting this O/P:-

> Enter temperature and wind Speed: 20 7 wind_chill is:11.03490062551

But I want to print all the decimal number till last without round up.

Expected O/P:-

> wind_chill = 11.034900625509998

By declaring variables as `decimal` and converting all the values in `decimal`:
I am getting this output:

> wind_chill = 11.034900625510096

Still not matching with the expected one. I searched But I didn't get my answer.How to get expected output?

Comment: Use decimal instead of double to get higher precision

Comment: Used decimal. It is rounding up. I want all the original decimal points

Comment: That's not possible it gives precision upto 28-29 digits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Comment: @Prabu- It's giving the value but rounding up I think. I need to match my output with the expected output.

Comment: @prabu: temp = 20 and wind speed = 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate the value with doubles. It is just that .NET will format the value to 15 characters when printing. Use R format to get all digits.

```
var wind_chill = WindChillDbl(20.0, 7.0);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:R}", wind_chill));

public static double WindChillDbl(double temp, double wind_speed)
{
    return 35.74 + 0.6215 * temp + (0.4275 * temp - 35.75) * System.Math.Pow(wind_speed, 0.16);
}
```

"By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. If the value of this instance has greater than 15 digits, ToString returns PositiveInfinitySymbol or NegativeInfinitySymbol instead of the expected number. If you require more precision, specify format with the "G17" format specification, which always returns 17 digits of precision, or "R", which returns 15 digits if the number can be represented with that precision or 17 digits if the number can only be represented with maximum precision." [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ Janne: Now O/P is coming: wind_chill = 11.034900625509991 Expected o/p:wind_chill = 11.034900625509998 why last 8 in expected o/p is converted to 1 in my o/p.

Comment: @ Janne: I need to match all the decimal points with the expected one

Comment: Where do you get your expected result value?

Comment: Some times they need 15 decimal points sometimes they need 14. Their system is using different test cases and showing me wrong output because now with "R" format my all the outputs having 15 decimal points. Can we switch between 14 and 15 Or their system is only wrong

Comment: I dont know what system you are talking about. Seems they are rounding things up in if the get the last digit as 8 instead 1. As @jrbeverly stated, it really is about the power calculation, if you do that in scientific calculator you will get far more precision than the 17 digits (1,3652610064150737737613938051401 in the windows default calculator)

Answer (score 3):

You can inspect your calculation to see that the values returned for most of the expression are accurate.  The problem is with the accuracy of `System.Math.Pow(wind_speed, 0.16);`.  If you look at [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E(0.16)) for that input, there are signifcantly more digits provided than the `1.36526100641507` returned by `Math.Pow`.

The reason for this is because `Math.pow` uses float point types which are inaccurate by design.  You may also be able to use `BigInteger` and figure out a way to make your equation work with that.

You can resolve this in a couple of ways:

1. Use [BigRational](https://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational&referringTitle=Home)
2. Rework the equation to somehow use `BigInteger`
3. See this question: [What is the equivalent of the Java BigDecimal class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2863388/2127492), specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813535/2127492

---

If you do go with the [BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813535/2127492) class provided in that answer, you will be able to make use of the method `BigDecimal Pow(double basis, double exponent)` to improve the accuracy your calculation.

You can see your calculation with the above class [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C15omp).